# Software that generates and solves a Lasserre hierarchy

Tags: convex-optimization, software

Suppose L is a linear program that is a relaxation of some 0/1 integer linear program ILP. There is a systematic way to construct SDP relaxations of ILP that are tighter than L by using a Lasserre hierarchy. There are many software tools available to solve linear programs (e.g. CPLEX, lpSOLVE, GLPK) . I am looking for a (free) software tool that can do the following. If I give a linear program and a number t as input, then the tool must output the optimal value of the objective and values of the SDP variables at the t-th level of hierarchy.

Comment: It seems to me that you want two different pieces of software. (1) an SDP solver and (2) a program that constructs the SDP at the $t$-th level of the hierarchy. Finding software for (1) is not hard.

Comment: Yes, a script that will do just (2) is also fine. But I expect some SDP solver to have this option.

Comment: What about the original code http://homepages.laas.fr/henrion/software/gloptipoly3/

Comment: as far as I know no SDP solver as this algorithm built in.